# Angular 2 ternary if to add disabled to an input

Tags: angular, ternary-operator

How may I add `disabled` to an `input` if a condition is met?

What I have today:
`<input class="previous" [attr.disabled] = "active === 1 ? 'disabled' : ''">`

But this adds `disabled="disabled"` and I want only `disabled`.

So what I need is: `<input class="previous" disabled>` if the condition is met.

Answer (score 59, accepted):

An attribute can be removed by passing the value `null`

```
[attr.disabled] = "active === 1 ? 'disabled' : null">
```

Comment: Sweet, it still prints `disabled="disabled"` but it solved my problem because when it's false, it will print nothing instead of `disabled=""`

Comment: @William If you want disabled to be reflected in DOM just like `disabled` and not `disabled="disabled"`, pass boolean value to disabled attribute: `[disabled]="active === 1 ? true : false"`

Comment: @stefan-svrkota removing the attribute or having the value set to `false` is quite a difference. Also the question was about removing.

Comment: the question is talking about how to disable an input conditionally. while changing the attr appears acceptable. a better solution may be as follows,

you can use something like below in the html

`<input [disabled]="shouldBeDisabled">`

and then in the TS
`get shouldBeDisabled():boolean {
    return {condition here as boolean};
}`